# Retrieve values from 2 tables given a value in a third map/join table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4

I have a table for `lawyers`:

```
CREATE TABLE lawyers (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR,
  name_url VARCHAR,
  pic_url VARCHAR(200)
);
```

Imagine the whole table looks like this:

[image]

And a table for `firms`:

```
CREATE TABLE firms (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR,
  address JSONb
);
```

Whole table:

[image]

Then to map many to many relationship I'm using a map table `lawyers_firms`:

```
CREATE TABLE lawyers_firms (
  lawyer_id INTEGER,
  firm_id INTEGER
 );
```

I'm not sure how to retrieve values from `lawyers`and from `firms`given a  `lawyers_firms.firm_id`.

For example:

```
1. SELECT name, name_url and pic_url FROM lawyers. 
2. also SELECT name and address FROM firms.
3. WHERE `lawyers_firms.firm_id` = 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT l.name, l.name_url, l.pic_url, f.name, f.address 
FROM lawyers l
 inner join lawyers_firms lf
 on lf.lawyer_id = l.id 
 inner join firms f
 on f.id = lf.firm_id
 WHERE lf.firm_id = 1;
```

Comment: Following link has a good explanation on table joins [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_joins.htm)

Comment: Wow that worked but had to made some minor fixes: please edit yout post so I can upvote and accept answer: SELECT l.name, l.name_url, l.pic_url, f.name, f.address 
FROM lawyers l 
inner join lawyers_firms lf on lf.lawyer_id = l.id
inner join firms f on f.id = lf.firm_id
WHERE lf.firm_id = 1;